# Is it possible to switch back and forth between Scenekit rendering and normal iOS app rendering?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

It would be nice to use the regular iOS app buttons during menu'ing, then go into Scenekit rendering for game play.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is possible, `SCNView` that is used for SceneKit rendering is just like any other `UIView` that you can use in your UI. You can even overlay SceneKit content with other `UIViews` and so on.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try!

Comment: Lesha, this worked really well (thanks).  What I've found so far is that using one ViewController and adding UIKit menus on top works well with no loss in FPS.  I tried multiple view controllers tied to scenekit - results varied.  While it worked, switching between a single view (modal) -has some issues.  In case anyone is trying this - watch where you put your buttons - it can have threading issues.